# Calculate Julian Day based on a different reference day

Tags: r, julian-date

My purpose is to calculate Julian Day based on a new reference, meaning that Julian Day 1 now will correspond to June 1st and Julian Day 366 to January 1st.

Hello everyone,

I've been struggling to calculate Julian Day where the reference day is not January 1st anymore.
Indeed, I want to extract from my data Julian Day where June 1st correspond to 1 and January 1st to 366.

I tried to add 152 to Julian Day calculated with January 1st as a reference however my data than exceed 366 and I don't think it's the exact solution.

I'm really confused and know it's about mathematical suite but I'm not comfortable with it.

If you could help me I would be very grateful :)

Comment: if `june 1st` is 1 then `may 31st` should be 366/5. How do you want january 1st to be 366? what kind of year is that? ie if you start from june 1st then you will end at may 31st

Comment: If June 1 is "julian 1", then I would expect Jan 1 to be "julian 214", not 366. How do you come by that number?

Comment: Yes, indeed you are right I've been thinking right. I was so focused on January 1st and June 1st.
Thank you for helping me noticing it

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you meant `May 31` instead of `Jan 1`, then a perhaps-convoluted method could start with:

```r
set.seed(42)
dates <- sort(as.Date("2020-06-01") + c(-1, 0, sample(1000, size=5)))
dates
# [1] "2020-05-31" "2020-06-01" "2020-08-14" "2020-11-01" "2021-04-18" "2021-12-14" "2023-02-23"
june1s <- as.POSIXlt(paste0(substring(dates, 1, 4), "-06-01"))
june1s
# [1] "2020-06-01 EDT" "2020-06-01 EDT" "2020-06-01 EDT" "2020-06-01 EDT" "2021-06-01 EDT" "2021-06-01 EDT"
# [7] "2023-06-01 EDT"
june1s$year <- june1s$year - (as.Date(june1s) > dates)
dates - as.Date(june1s) + 1L
# Time differences in days
# [1] 366   1  75 154 322 197 268
as.numeric(dates - as.Date(june1s) + 1L, units = "days")
# [1] 366   1  75 154 322 197 268
```

I included `05-31` and `06-01` to demonstrate the two extremes of the June-1-based-julian-year. The last step (`as.numeric`) is mostly a defensive habit of mine: `difftime` and similar functions often auto-change the units based on the scale of the difference, and that might be problematic; using `units="days"` forces this. (There are other ways to deal with this, as well.)

One can functionize this with:

```r
myjulian <- function(dates, origin = "-01-01") {
  if (!inherits(dates, "Date")) dates <- as.Date(dates)
  origins <- as.POSIXlt(paste0(substring(dates, 1, 4), origin))
  origins$year <- origins$year - (as.Date(origins) > dates)
  as.numeric(dates - as.Date(origins) + 1L, units = "days")
}
```

With brief validation:

```r
myjulian("2023-06-01") # jan-1
# [1] 152
format(as.Date("2023-06-01"), format = "%j")
# [1] "152"

myjulian("2023-06-01", origin = "-06-01")
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working !! 
I can use it directly on my data frame with a column of data with the format POSIXCT